# Problema ao executar uma consulta em um laço de repetição no Node Mssql

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, callback

Então,

Estou utilizando node e pacote mssql (sql-server) para realizar consultas ao meu banco de dados.

porém estou enfrentando uma dificuldade para retorno de consultas que precisam ser executadas dentro de um laço de repetição.

talvez seja alguma coisa haver com a forma que estou realizando o callback.
Em outras consultas nas quais eu não preciso realizar um laço de repetição, funciona normalmente.

Meu controller:

```
api.contabilizacaoItems =  function (req, res, next) {
    itensParaEnvio = [];
    var dados = req.body;
    cont = 1
    console.log(dados.items.length);
    dados.items.forEach(function (item, key){ 
        item.aprovacao = dados.aprovacao
        solicitacaoSqlDAO.contabilizacaoItem(item, function (erro, recordset) {
           item.contItem= recordset.recordset;
           solicitacaoSqlDAO.aenItem(item, function (erro, recordset) {
               item.aenItens= recordset.recordset;
               itensParaEnvio[key]= item;
               if(cont == dados.items.length) res.status(200).json(itensParaEnvio);
               else res.status(404).json("erro");
           })
       })
    });  
};

return api;
```

Meu DAO

```
solicitacaoDAO.prototype.contabilizacaoItem = function (item, callback) {
  console.log("# PARA CONSULTA contabilizacaoItem# ");
  mssql.close();
  mssql.connect(this._connection, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("# ERRO AO REALIZAR CONEXAO PARA CONSULTA contabilizacaoItem# "+ err);
    }
    var request = new mssql.Request();
    query = "select * from alguma coisa ";
    // console.log(query);
    request.query(query, function (err, recordset) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(query);
        callback(err,recordset);
      } else {
        callback(err,recordset);
      }   
    });
  });
}

solicitacaoDAO.prototype.aenItem = function (item, callback) {
  console.log("# PARA CONSULTA aenItem# ");

  mssql.close();
  mssql.connect(this._connection, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("# ERRO AO REALIZAR CONEXAO PARA CONSULTA aenItem# "+ err);
    }

    var request = new mssql.Request();
    query = "select * from alguma coisa"
    // console.log(query);
    request.query(query, function (err, recordset) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(query);
        callback(err,recordset);
      } else {
        callback(err,recordset);
      }   
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize promessas para resolver apenas quando todos os `callbacks` forem finalizados:

```
api.contabilizacaoItems = function(req, res, next) {
  var itensParaEnvio = [];
  var dados          = req.body;
  var promessas      = [];

  console.log(dados.items.length);

  dados.items.forEach(function(item, key) {
    promessas.push(new Promise(function(resolver, rejeitar) {
      item.aprovacao = dados.aprovacao;

      solicitacaoSqlDAO.contabilizacaoItem(item, function(erro, recordset) {
        item.contItem = recordset.recordset;

        solicitacaoSqlDAO.aenItem(item, function(erro, recordset) {
          item.aenItens       = recordset.recordset;
          itensParaEnvio[key] = item;

          resolver();
        })
      });
    }));
  });

  Promise.all([true, promessas]).then(function(values) {
    res.status(200).json(itensParaEnvio);
  }).catch(function() {
    res.status(404).json("erro");
  });
};
```

Comment: opa, vlw sorack, vou tesar mais tarde e te aviso

Comment: sorack, estou tentando usar, porém ele ainda continua travando no primeiro laço

Comment: @CiroStodulskideAzevedo qual o sintoma?

Comment: assim ele executa o primeira vez e passa sem executar os proximos..
eu to vendo que é promessas que pode resolver mas acho que não to sabendo implementar.

Comment: Estou tendo problema no meo DAO, mas tive outra forma de solucionar o problema, não era do jeito que queria mas serviu no momento,
obrigado pela ajuda!